# Access data with through option on models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

"Hi guys!" I'm currently working with a project on Rails. I have three tables.

```
class CreateDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :doctors do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

    class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

    class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.date :date_appointment
      t.references :doctor, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :patient, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I have been able to insert data in the table called appointment and access data from other tables thanks to the foreign keys. what I want to do now is to access data from the table "doctors" to "patients" and vice-versa. for example; I want to know how many Patients, "X" Doctor has. Is possible to do this?

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :doctor
      belongs_to :patient
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Doctor.first.patients
Doctor.find(1).patients
Doctor.find_by(name: "aaron").patients
Patient.first.doctors
Patient.find(1).doctors
Patient.find_by(name: "dhh").doctors
```

Those are just some examples.

Comment: Doctor.find_by(name: "aaron").patients <---- this did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**for example; I want to know how many Patients, "X" Doctor has:**

```
doctor = Doctor.find_by(name: 'X')
doctor.patients.count
#=> number of patients of doctor with the name 'X'
```

I advise to read about [`ActiveRecord` querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) in the Rails guide.

Comment: you know I actually was reading that article. And only with your comment I was able to understand the concept. Thank you very much your time!